# What exactly are LDFLAGS and CXXFLAGS?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, centos6

I have read for some installation, I need to set up environment variables LDFLAGS, LD_LIBRARY_PATHS and CXXFLAGS correctly for ./compile.sh to run. However, I am not sure what path to give there. Can someone please explain what those flags mean and what are they used for? Are they something related to the gcc installation?

I am working on CENTOS 6.6 with default gcc 4.4.7 but I want to use gcc 4.9.1 which is installed in /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc.

I tried to look up other similar questions but did not get my answer. i want to know what exactly the paths/flags mean.

I am new to Linux so please disregard my ignorance. Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `compile.sh` is, but `CXXFLAGS` is a standard variable that GNU make uses as the flags to pass to the C++ compiler when using implicit rules. Same with `LDFLAGS`. [Full list here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables). Your `compile.sh` most probably invokes `make` at some point, which then uses these variables to set appropriate linker/compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks @DanielKamilKozar! I am trying to install bazel on my machine and just following the instructions given [here](http://www.bazel.io/docs/install.html) and it does not seem to be very straight forward. So I was looking at some issue on github where they said I need to update all these environment variables.

Comment: CentOS 6,8 - 64 : `cd bazel-0.3.0/` ; `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash && ./compile.sh` : Runs OK till item #689, then exits with » gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus) « , » Elapsed time: 322.769s «.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS 6.8 - x86_64 :

Using bazel-0.3.0.tar.gz https://codeload.github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tar.gz/0.3.0 , and devtoolset-4 . (`devtoolset-4-gcc, *-4-gcc-c++` provides gcc 5.3.1 ).

```
cd bazel-0.3.0/
scl enable devtoolset-4 bash && ./compile.sh
```

> Build successful! Binary is here:
>   /home/knudfl/tmp/bazel-0.3.0/output/bazel

Note : The complete devtoolset-4 is not required. This will do : `yum install devtoolset-4-gcc-c++` ( Which will install 5 packages only.)

Comment: Thanks @KnudLarsen.

I can not use bazel 0.3.0. I ultimately have to install google syntaxnet on CentOS 6.6. Bazel is just stage 1. Then I need to install tensorflow and have syntaxnet running. Can you please look at my problem description [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/276) and suggest something?

Comment: » `devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.1/libstdc++_nonshared.a(hashtable_c++0x.o): undefined reference to` **symbol 'ceil@@GLIBC_2.2.5'** « : Conclusion → `devtoolset-3` cannot be used. .... What we know is that `syntaxnet` builds OK with e.g. gcc-4.9.x ... I will upload like "gcc-c++-4.9.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm", and edit my above answer with some information.